# Split string by special characters '\.'

Tags: batch-file, split

I have a string which ends with `\.`.  All I want is the string before `\.`

Ex.:
My String is: `D:\Work\WelCome\.`
Output String should be: `D:\Work\WelCome`

Please excuse if you find this question very general. I have search on net of splitting string by special characters but did not get the expected result.

I am not very new to batch scripting but not enough expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a file/folder path, it is easier to let the os solve it for you than having to split the string (if you only need the left part)

```dos
for %%a in ("D:\Work\WelCome\.") do echo %%~fa
```

In the theoretical case that the ending dot could include aditional data (but no more backslashes), this can be converted to

```dos
rem The string with more data
set "myString=D:\Work\WelCome\.blah"

for %%a in ("%myString%.@\..") do echo %%~fa
```

The aditional `@` ensures that there is always aditional information (that way the previous dot ending case will still work), the `for` command will see a file reference and we just need to get the reference to the parent folder.

**But** note this is only a way to clean a file/folder reference, not a way to split the string on an precise character.

For an easy solution to split the string (or to be more precise, remove the suffix)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem The string
    set "myString=D:\Work\WelCome\.test"

rem Do the split
    set "myString=%myString:\.="&rem %"
    set "myString=%myString%"

rem Show data 
    echo %myString%
```

It replaces the splitting substring with a command concatenation and a comment start (`rem`). So

```dos
set "myString=D:\Work\WelCome\.test"
```

is converted into

```dos
set "myString=D:\Work\WelCome"& rem test"
```

This way, in the next line, when the variable is assigned to itself, the unneeded part will be removed (hidden by the `rem`).

Comment: That doesn't work for cases like `D:\Work\WelCome\.blah` which would keep the blah. While I completely agree with you, the OP specifically said split, which I thought might imply possible characters following the path

Comment: @Monacraft, of course, you are right. Now this is stated in the answer that this is not a way to "split" the string. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this code and it works:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set p=D:\Work\WelCome\.
set v=
::  v is the output
for %%a in (%p:.= %) do (
  set "v=!v!.%%~a"
  set q=%%~a
  if "!q:~-1!"=="\" goto :end
)
:end
set v=%v:~1%
set v=%V:~0,-1%
echo %v%
```

Here are cases I used:

```
C:\> split.bat C:\1\2\3\.
C:\1\2\3

C:\> split.bat C:\1\2\3\.4\5\
C:\1\2\3

C:\> split.bat C:\1\2\3\.4\5\.6\7\8
C:\1\2\3

C:\> split.bat C:\1\2.\ .3.\...4\.5
C:\1\2.\ .3.

C:\> split.bat C:\.1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\
C:
```

Which is what you were looking for. If you want to do more with the variable then just `echo` it simply refer to `%v%` following that line.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "string=D:\Work\WelCome\."

:: Classic solution if the string is in an environment variable

ECHO %string:~0,-2%

:: solution if the string is in a metavariable

FOR %%z IN ("%string%") DO ECHO %%z becomes %%~dpnz

GOTO :EOF
```

which should be self-explanatory.